# Output buffering in a while loop renders broken html from template

Tags: php, ajax

I'm doing an ajax call to a php script, and utilizing output buffering to increase the speed of the response. My problem is that the output is occasionally outputting broken html as it loops through each record.

Basically I'm looping through records that are formatted into a template at times a partial template is returned which breaks the view.

I've tried:

```
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression',0);

ob_start();
do{

    // php template here
    ob_end_flush(); //ob_end_clean();
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs));
```

What I'd like is to have php output the sections in complete blocks, not partial.

**Update**: 
I tried ob_end_flush(); but it's still outputting broken html structure from the template.

Comment: Would think you would be starting buffer before loop and doing an `ob_end_flush` at the end. I'm confused about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Right `ob_end_clean();` cleans/clears the buffer so there is NO output.

Comment: that's a typo. The ob_start(); is before the the loop.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. I believe this has to do with the size of the output buffer. if part of my template is returned to the browser, that might be why it's rendering incorrectly.

Comment: Would place the flush outside the loop. Sounds like your issues has nothing to do with output buffering. Maybe you are generating bad markup from your template. With the pseudo code you've shared there isn't much more we can do to help.

Comment: Well easy to test. Change `output_buffering` if you are sending more than the default 4 kb.

Comment: I tried placing the flush outside the loop and I still get broken markup in the browser. 

the template markup is ok on it's own. it renders ok when not using output buffering. As a background to what im' doing. I'm calling a php script from ajax that returns 50 records at a time (lazy loads at bottom of browser after each 50). 

Each record is a formatted in an html template. I'm attempting to speed up this process so the browser updates faster instead of waiting for all 50 records to load.

Comment: Sounds like you want a web socket. Xhr still follows rules of HTTP. Try `ob_implicit_flush()`, or add flush calls at end of each pass in loop, but honestly a lot of factors, server, browser, etc.

Comment: Consider pre buffering? Sounds like what you really want is a better user experience. Pull the next 25 before you need them, scroll a bit, fetch the rows, be ready to 'show' them to the user, they will not perceive the delay then. This widget does lazy loading very well if you want an example: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html

Comment: Pre buffering is a great idea. I'm looking into that link now.